# example to use configMap in Scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest

Basically what I need is an example on how to use the configMap class in a scalatest project so that I can

1. reference the confg values in the source code
2. use -Dparametername=value in the command line to run Scalatest using Scalatest Runner, for example
   `scala -classpath scalatest-<version>.jar org.scalatest.tools.Runner -Dparam1=value1 -p compiled_tests`

I am using Scalatest 1.6.1, the information here http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.6.1/org/scalatest/Suite.html#configMapSection is not very specific, and the examples in how to use configMap [here](http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.6.1/org/scalatest/fixture/FixtureSuite.html)in FixtureSuite doesn't seem to work with Scalatest-1.6.1

Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config map is passed around to a lot of places. How you'd use it depends on what you need to do. Can you supply more info on what you are trying to accomplish?

The config map is passed to run, runTests, runTest, runNestedSuites, and withFixture (both the NoArgTest and the OneArgTest variety), so you can pick it up from any of these by overriding the method in your test class. It is also passed to an overloaded form of beforeEach if you mix in BeforeAndAfterEach.

The withFixture(OneArgTest) example you pointed to should work in 1.6.1. I'll check it to make sure.